# When can I rely on Haskell to read a list lazily?

Tags: haskell, lazy-sequences

Why do I get an infinite loop (`<<loop>>`) runtime error here?

file feedback.hs:

```
plus1 :: [Int]->[Int] -- add 1 to input stream
plus1 [] = []
plus1 (x:xs) = (x+1): plus1 xs

to10 :: [Int] -> [Int] -- stop the input stream when it gets to 10
to10 (x:xs) | x < 10 = x : to10 xs
            | otherwise = []

to10plus :: [Int] -> ([Int], Int) -- like to10 but also return the count
to10plus (x:xs) | x < 10 = (x, 1) `merge` (to10plus xs)
            | otherwise = ([], 0)
  where merge (a, b) (as, bs) = (a:as, b+bs)

main = do
  let out = plus1 $ 1: to10 out
  putStrLn $ show out -- gives [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


  let out = plus1 $ 1: out2
      out2 = to10 out
  putStrLn $ show out -- same as above

  let out = plus1 $ 1: out2
      (out2, count) = to10plus out
  putStrLn $ show (out, count) -- expect ([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 8) 
                               -- but get runtime error: <<loop>>
```

```
$ ghc feedback.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( feedback.hs, feedback.o )
Linking feedback ...
$ ./feedback
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
feedback: <<loop>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix `to10plus` by using an irrefutable match (i.e., a `~` prefix) in your definition of `merge`:

```
merge (a, b) ~(as, bs) = (a:as, b+bs)
```

The reason for the difference in behavior between `to10` and `to10plus` is that `to10` can return the first element of the list without having to evaluate `to10 xs` and so without inspecting `xs`.

In contrast, before it can return anything, `to10plus` must successfully call `merge` with the arguments `(x, 1)` and `to10plus xs`.  For this call to succeed, `to10plus xs` must be evaluated far enough to ensure it matches the pattern `(as, bs)` used in the definition of `merge`, but that evaluation requires inspecting elements of `xs`, which aren't available yet.

You could also have avoided the problem by defining `to10plus` a little differently:

```
to10plus (x:xs) | x < 10 = (x:as,1+bs)
                | otherwise = ([], 0)
  where (as,bs) = to10plus xs
```

Here, `to10plus` can provide the first element `x` of the first part of the tuple without trying to evaluate `as`, and so without trying to pattern match `to10plus xs` with `(as,bs)` in the `where` clause.  A `let` clause would have done the same thing:

```
to10plus (x:xs) | x < 10 = let (as,bs) = to10plus xs in (x:as,1+bs)
                | otherwise = ([], 0)
```

As @luqui points out, this is a difference in the timing for pattern matches made by `let` and `where` statements:

```
let (a,b) = expr in body
-- OR --
body where (a,b) = expr
```

versus `case` statements / function definitions:

```
case expr of (a,b) -> body
-- OR --
f (a,b) = body  -- AND THEN EVALUATING: -- f expr
```

The `let` and `where` statements match patterns lazily, meaning that `expr` isn't matched to the pattern `(a,b)` until `a` or `b` are evaluated in the `body`.  In contrast, for the `case` statement, `expr` is matched to `(a,b)` right away, before the `body` is even examined.  And given the above definition for `f`, the argument to `f` will be matched to `(a,b)` as soon as the expression `f expr` is evaluated without waiting until `a` or `b` is needed in the function `body`.  Here are some working examples to illustrate:

```
ex1 = let (a,b) = undefined in print "okay"
ex2 = print "also okay" where (a,b) = undefined
ex3 = case undefined of (a,b) -> print "not okay"
ex4 = f undefined
f (a,b) = print "also not okay"

main = do
  ex1   -- works
  ex2   -- works
  ex3   -- fails
  ex4   -- fails
```

Adding `~` changes the behavior for `case` / function definitions so the matching takes place only when `a` or `b` are needed:

```
ex5 = case undefined of ~(a,b) -> print "works fine"
ex6 = g undefined
g ~(a,b) = print "also works fine"

ex7 = case undefined of ~(a,b) -> print $ "But trying " ++ show (a+b) ++ " would fail"
```

Comment: The key difference is far from self-evident and should probably be stated: pattern matches in `let` and `where` are always lazy, but patterns for arguments default to strict unless made lazy using `~`.

Comment: Thank you K. A. Buhr and luqui!